# Click on "Login Button" not working for Selenium Java code

Tags: java, button, selenium, authentication, automation

Trying to automate a login page. The HTML for the button is below:

```
button class="btn loginBtn " style="" tabindex="3" type="submit">Login</button
```

Java code:

```
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
wd.findElement(By.id("btn loginBtn")).click();
```

But this throws the below error.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"btn loginBtn"}
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
System info: host: 'techteam-PC', ip: '192.168.10.150', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Session ID: 8b0100ab-bb50-469c-ada6-ad9f9c21d525
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=30.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at AutoStaging.main(AutoStaging.java:24)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"btn loginBtn"}
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
System info: host: 'techteam-PC', ip: '192.168.10.150', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/techteam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8022566380795403314webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9470:7)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/techteam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8022566380795403314webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9479:3)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/techteam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8022566380795403314webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455:11)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/techteam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8022566380795403314webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460:7)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/techteam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8022566380795403314webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402:5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button have class `loginBtn` not id `loginBtn`
Try `wd.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'loginBtn')]")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching id for all the web elements use the firebug add on tool in firefix and get the xPath for it. Then you can use the below code:

```
wd.findElement(By.xPath("yourXpathUsingFirebug")).click();
```

Comment: id('loginPalette')/x:form/x:fieldset/x:button  --- is the xpath for the login button..  wd.findElement(By.xpath("id('loginPalette')/x:form/x:fieldset/x:button")).click(); is my code.. but it still throws an error

Comment: no ideally xPath will be in //*[@id='tour-switch-page']/nav/div[2]/h1 format.
First go to Mozilla Firefox, Click on Menu Tools->Add-ons.(alternately,Ctrl+Shift+A). Then search for firebug install it and also search firepath and install that as well. Both should get installed and restart firefox. You should be able to see a bug icon at the top right corner of firefox.
Navigate to your webpage, click the bug icon. Select Firepath tab in the bottom panel. Select inspect element icon(rectangle box with arrow) and click your button. You see the xPath for that it. Use that in the code I mentioned